# Error showing when calling ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm requesting a Ajax call by Jquery `.blur()` method. But it's showing me error message. Do you know why it's showing me error message ?

**Following is my Jquery/Ajax Code:**

```
<script>
$("#given_name").blur(function(){   

var given_name =  $("#given_name").val(); 

$.ajax({
  url: 'certainfield.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: given_name,
}).done(function ( data ) {
  $('#r').append(data);
});

});
</script>
```

**Html Code:**

```
<tr>
<td>Given name</td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $res['given_name'] ?>" name="given_name" 
id="given_name" placeholder="Given name"/></td>
</tr>
```

**Php page Code :**

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "we are printing certain file <br/>";
$msg =  $_POST['given_name'];
echo $msg;  
?>
```

**Error Message :**

```
Notice: Undefined index: given_name in D:\software installed\xampp\htdocs\contact-management
\certainfield.php on line 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `data` format is incorrect, change:

```
..
data: given_name,
..
```

to

```
...
data: {"given_name" : given_name},
...
```

See [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$("#given_name").blur(function(){   

    var given_name =  $(this).val(); 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'certainfield.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {"given_name" : given_name},
    }).done(function ( data ) {
        $('#r').append(data);
    });

});
```

Comment: @Sundhir Oh I see my issue. Thanks it's working but I get one error message on Console Log that is `TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function`. Do you know what is this ?

Comment: @Shibbir you dont seem to have $.validate() in posted code, but it seems you have not added jquery.validate.js in your page and hence error is shown..! Be sure to add your jquery.validate.js file after adding jquery.js..!

Comment: @Shibbir glad that you got it. Btw, you could mark it as accepted answer if it worked for you.. :)

Comment: @Shundhir I've a another questions that is : Now I'm using blur() method on 1 field. So how do i use this blue() method to other 3 fields(I've another 3 fields which is : email, p_email, phone). Can you help me with that ?

Comment: @Shibbir you could do: $("#given_name, #email, #phone").blur(function(){ ... }, i.e you could use comma separated list of selectors using same blur() function